# jquery to select its children 1 after another?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

This is my html code:

```
<ul id="menuDots">
    <li id="about1"><a href="#"><img class="bulletRoll" src="images/menu-dot.png" /><img src="images/menu-dot-rollover.png" /></a></li>
    <li id="about2"><a href="#"><img class="bulletRoll" src="images/menu-dot.png" /><img src="images/menu-dot-rollover.png" /></a></li>
    <li id="about3"><a href="#"><img class="bulletRoll" src="images/menu-dot.png" /><img src="images/menu-dot-rollover.png" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

right now I'm targeting bulletRoll class, is there a jquery function then can select bulletRoll 1 after another? Let say if I'm on the second bulletRoll class then I trigger the same function again it will go to the nearest previous/next bulletRoll class?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery's next](http://api.jquery.com/next/) and / or [prev](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) selector to do so.

E.g.

```
var next = $(this).next("li");
if (next.length){   // there is another li
   myfunction(next);  //trigger same function
}
```

For your use case it might be simpler to use [jQuery's each function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) though as it will iterate through each element in your selection without having to call a function recursively:

```
$("li").each(function(index, value){
   // do something with the element $(this)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) and [.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) functions of jQuery.

```
var current = $("li:first");
if(current.next().length){ //for next. If next exists,
   current = current.next():
   trigger_function(current);
}
if(current.prev().length){ //Similarly for prev,
   current = current.prev():
   trigger_function(current);
}
```